# Is this HSTS header set correctly in LAMP?

Tags: apache, hsts

I have a LAMP server and my SSL certificate provider recommended me to set HSTS header as follows in Apache2:

```
Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; preload" env=HTTPS
```

Questions:

1. What does `preload` do?
2. What does `env=HTTPS` do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1. What does `preload` do?

The preload flag indicates consent for the domain to be allowed onto the [HSTS preload list](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/net/http/transport_security_state_static.json) (used by Chrome, Firefox, IE 11, Edge, and other browsers).

> The Chrome security team allows any domain to submit their domain to the list, provided it meets the following requirements:

> - HTTPS is enabled on the root domain (e.g. `https://donotcall.gov`), and **all subdomains** (e.g. `https://www.donotcall.gov`) – especially the `www` subdomain, if a DNS record for it exists.

- The HSTS policy includes all subdomains, with a long `max-age`, and a `preload` flag to indicate that the domain owner consents to preloading.
- The website redirects from HTTP to HTTPS, at least on the root domain.

Source: https://https.cio.gov/hsts/#hsts-preloading

You can see more information on the [HSTS Preload Submission](https://hstspreload.appspot.com/) page.

### 2. What does `env=HTTPS` do?

This is an argument of the Apache `Header` directive (part of the [mod_headers module](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html)):

> **`env=[!]varname`**
>
> The directive is applied if and only if the environment variable `varname` exists. A `!` in front of `varname` reverses the test, so the directive applies only if `varname` is unset.

In this case, the HTTP header is only sent when the `HTTPS` environment variable is set. This environment variable is only set when pages/resources are accessed via HTTPS. The reasoning behind this is in [section 7.2 of the HSTS specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6797#section-7.2):

> An HSTS Host MUST NOT include the STS header field in HTTP responses conveyed over non-secure transport.

As to *why*, see [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/84714/why-does-rfc6797-say-an-hsts-host-must-not-include-the-sts-header-field-in-http/84718#84718).